# Adding custom intent filter (exampleapp://...) to android project throws error

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, rename, android-deep-link

The project builds properly, however starting it on the device / emulator fails. Odd thing is, that the package name is called two times before the .MainActivity part comes. So the error makes total sense as to there isn't a folder name com/example/myapp/com/example/myapp. However I don't understand why it is being called / concatenated twice?

With the default `<intent-filter>` the app runs without errors, however without the possibility of deeplinking when calling `exampleapp://...`.

Would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Following error is shown in the logs:

> Error while executing: am start -n
> "com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity" -a
> android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
> cmp=com.example.myapp/.MainActivity } Error type 3 Error: Activity
> class {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity} does not
> exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity Failed to launch an application on all
> devices

**Custom intent filter:**

```xml
<intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "exampleapp://facebook” or "exampleapp://google" "exampleapp://payment -->
              <data android:scheme="exampleapp" android:host="facebook" />
              <data android:scheme="exampleapp" android:host="google" />
              <data android:scheme="exampleapp" android:host="payment" />
 </intent-filter>
```

What exactly is wrong defining the `<intent-filter>` like above? Android Studio underlines the word `exampleapp` and shows *Typo in word 'exampleapp'* and suggests me to change it to `applicative`.

I don't really understand what this warning means and why it worked in my previous project without any problems in first place?

Answer (score 0):

> com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

`com.example.myapp` is your application package name

`com.example.myapp.MainActivity` is your fully qualified class name, i.e. the java package plus the java class name.

Ensure that your applicationId matches your package name, and ensure that your `MainActivity` is in a java package of `com/example/myapp/MainActivity`.

---

After your question edit:

Make a separate intent-filter.

Make one filter with just the action and category without the data, the system will use that one.

Then separately, make your custom schema's in another intent-filter for your internal navigation.

Comment: hey would you mind to check my **edit**. It was something related to the `<intent-filter>` within my manifest file.

Comment: Your scheme should be a scheme (like `http`). https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#scheme You really shouldn't edit your question to be so different :-)

Comment: Sorry for that kind of a big edit, but it turned out, that my issue weren't related to renaming the project. Well this is a custom scheme and my scheme was `myappname` in other projects and I was able to define and use such local schemes in different projects before.

Comment: Make a separate intent-filter. Make one filter with just the action and category without the data, the system will use that one. Then separately, make your custom schema's in another intent-filter for your internal navigation.

Comment: Tried that already, unfortunately same error is thrown.

Comment: So then you may be back to your first error.

Comment: if any <data> is specified in the intent filter the app throws the error, however doing it in seperate intent-filters the error is not thrown and I am able to start the app on the device, however the deeplink wont work. It even doesn't work if I specify an url as deeplink with scheme "https" and host "myapp.com".

Comment: which is another separate question, sorry, that's how stackoverflow works :-)